# MediaPlayer keeps playing although i closed the app

Tags: android

i've got this Activity and as soon as i hit the home button during the playback of the sounds
the sounds keep playing and when the sound is finished it brings back the app.

```
public class View5 extends MasterView implements OnCompletionListener {

    int[] tracks = new int[4];
    int[] times = new int[4];
    int currentTrack = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = getAssets().open("herzdruck_animiert2.gif");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        String lang = settings.getString("lang", "");


        if (lang.equals("de")) {
            tracks[0] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_1_de",
                    null, this.getPackageName());

            tracks[1] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_2_de", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

            tracks[2] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_3_de", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

            tracks[3] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_4_de", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

        } else if (lang.equals("tr")) {
            tracks[0] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_1_tr",
                    null, this.getPackageName());

            tracks[1] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_2_tr", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

            tracks[2] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_3_tr", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

            tracks[3] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_4_tr", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

        } else if (lang.equals("en")) {
            tracks[0] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_1_en",
                    null, this.getPackageName());

            tracks[1] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_2_en", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

            tracks[2] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_3_en", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

            tracks[3] = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/view5_4_en", null,
                    this.getPackageName());

        }

        times[0] = 5000;
        times[1] = 2000;
        times[2] = 2000;
        times[3] = 1000;

        GifMovieView view = new GifMovieView(this, stream);

         mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
         mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
         mPlayer.start();



        setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        arg0.release();
        arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                tracks[currentTrack]);

        if (currentTrack < tracks.length-1) {
            currentTrack++;
            arg0 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                    tracks[currentTrack]);
            arg0.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(times[currentTrack]);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            arg0.start();
        }else if(currentTrack==tracks.length-1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewBeat1.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

How can i get rid of this behaviour?

The MasterView holds the mPlayer and also closes it onRestart, onDestroy and onPause.

Comment: I've had this same problem before. You need to explicitly stop the music in onPause. Your last comment sounds like you are. Can you show us that code instead?

Comment: I'm doing this in the MasterView (which extends from Activity)
protected void onPause() {
  mPlayer.release();
  super.onPause();
  
 }

Comment: Unrelated but...may I suggest *not* naming classes `View5` and to take the three seconds it takes to change an argument's name from `arg0` to anything more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Here is the state diagram of the `MediaPlayer` that will help you to understand at what point in the `Activity`'s life cycle should you call the various methods on your `MediaPlayer` object.

Just like `Jesse J` said, try calling `stop()` in `onPause()`